# openmp construct with, memcpy insides the for loop results in wrong output values

Tags: c++, c, openmp, memcpy

I'm trying to copy input buffer values into the multiple output buffers. To do this, i have used memcpy(..) inside the for loop. To get the better performance i have used the openmp construct outside of the for loop. I'm gaining some performance improvement but it results in wrong output buffer values.

In my project, i tried to use memcpy to copy some channels of input image into the output buffers. And i have used openmp construct outside of the loop. I am getting incorrect output values.

```
// sudo code to copy required channels from ipBuffer.
/* ipBuffer - input buffer 
 * opBuffer[] - Array of output bufferc
 * opChnls[] - How many channels does each ouput buffer needed from input.
 */
#pragma omp parallel for
   for (int i = 0; i < bs; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < numOutBufs; j++) {

            long int opElemPerBatch = opChnls[j] * inputH * inputW;
            std::memcpy(opBuffers[j] + opMemOffsets[j], ipBuffer + ipMemOffset, sizeof(float) * opElemPerBatch);

            ipMemOffset += (opElemPerBatch);
            opMemOffsets[j] += opElemPerBatch;
        }

    }
```

My main concern is to performance need to imroved with same accuracy. I new to openmp. 
Could anyone please help in understand openmp construct with memcpy in for loop in detailed manner?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest if you are in C++ space, do this the C++ way by working with constructors /  copy constructors instead.

Comment: @Tzalumen my concern is to use both openmp and memcpy.

Comment: Parallelism breaks your `ipMemOffset` and `opMemOffsets[j]` updates.  Luckily, you can calculate these from `i` and `j`.

Comment: While I understand what you are asking for, I am saying that using memcpy in C++ is highly inadvisable. Your problem only exists because you are trying to use C-style memory manipulation instead of C++ style memory manipulation and C++ style data constructs

Comment: Presently your code is broken. You cannot accumulate in global vars like that, otherwise you will have races and an incorrect result. For the scalar you can use a reduction. For the array declare a per thread array accumulate in it and add the result in global array with an atomic operation.

Comment: @AlainMerigot correct me if I'm wrong. After your suggestion I just go through my code once. I found opMemOffests can be local array to inner for loop but I feel remaining all variables are must be global because one thread output depends on other. Also I had a thought to use number of openmp threads as number of output buffers.

Comment: Yes, you only have to render local data that may be modified concurrently. But I have problems understanding what does your code. And why you use openmp. You will gain **nothing** (and you may even loose performances) parallelizing memcpy.  Look at the end of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782033/why-is-linear-read-shuffled-write-not-faster-than-shuffled-read-linear-write/54935680) where  there are some timings.

Comment: @AlainMerigot  I will let you understand my code. Lets say input image size 5x5x30x2(Height*Width*Channels*BatchSize) then i'm trying to copy input data in channel wise to the different two output buffers with sizes  5x5x20x2 and 5x5x10x2.

Comment: @AlainMerigot I have generic question, Does parallelizing memcpy using memcpy will results in any performance gain?

Comment: No. Look at the link that I gave previously. I timed parallelized memcpy (among other things) and the gain is null or very small. And can even be slightly negative...

Comment: @AlainMerigot apart from performance improvement, what is the reason for getting wrong output values in my code using the openmp.

Comment: Because you concurrently modify a global variable. There are races and the result can be wrong. You need atomic operations to do that.

Comment: @AlainMerigot, i made ipMemOffset and opMemOffsets as private variables to the openmp construct so that these variables are atomic to each thread but i'm encountered with segmentation fault. (or) Is there any other alternative to make memcpy as atomic operation and no need to depend on the ipMemOffset and opMemOffet ?

Comment: @AlainMerigot it's not true that `memcpy` does not benefit from parallelization. Even on modern desktop CPUs one core can no longer fully saturate the memory bandwidth, although the gap isn't huge. On bigger NUMA systems the difference is drastic. See also these [benchmark results](https://panthema.net/2013/pmbw/results.html) (unfortunately for scan, not copy). Your timings  don't include system spec or code, so I can't comment. Anyway, parallelizing `memcpy` is probably a bad strategy for improving performance. One rather needs to think about avoiding data movement and data placement.

Comment: @AlainMerigot reduction on `ipMemOffset` and `opMemOffsets` won't work given that these are used in addressing within the loop.

Comment: @Zulan, why parallelizing memcpy is a bad strategy? Is there any reason?

Comment: Let's assume for a moment you already have done a proper performance analysis and identified the `memcpy` as a bottleneck. Also let's assume you are on a NUMA system where the possible benefit makes it worthwhile. First, you try to avoid the `memcpy` in your application by applying Zero-copy. If that is not possible. You think about your memory layout in the first place. Which thread works on what data? Keep memory as close as possible to the threads that are working on it - consider that for the copy. Bottom line: There are better ways to improve performance.